# iOS Simulate GPS

Tags: c#, ios, bluetooth, nmea

I would like to use C# to broadcast position data over bluetooth to an iPad to simulate an external bluetooth receiver. I am assuming it will be sent as NMEA data however I cannot find a specification for iOS that provides for how to send position data to be considered as an external GPS (Example: BadElf etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The BadElf products are MFi certified - this means that they include an Apple identity chip that allows them to work with the External Connectivity framework and legacy Bluetooth (probably Serial Port Protocol).  You can't emulate this hardware.

Comment: Paul thanks for the answer, I'll have to find another solution!